# C# DataGridView: Selected Row always returns First Row (Regardless of Selection)

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview, selection

I have a `DataGridView` in which the User selects a Row, and presses a Button which acts based off of the Selected Row.

Currently, I am trying to get the ID *(First Column)* of the Selected Row using the following method:

```
int id = (int) DataGrid_Contact.SelectedRow[0].Cells[0].Value;
```

I have tried other methods, such as `dgv.CurrentRow`, `dgv.SelectedCells`, etc. Everything always points to either the First Row, or the First Cell *(0, 0)*. Regardless of my selection, I cannot get this to change.

The notable properties of the `DataGridView` are:

```
MultiSelect = false;
ReadOnly = true;
SelectMode = FullRowSelect;
```

Everything else is either unrelated to Selection and/or set to their default values.

In case it matters, I am populating the DataGridView with an SQL Command, and setting the DataSource of the `DataGridView`. I've tried `this.BindingContext[DataGridView dgv.DataSource].EndCurrentEdit()` to no avail.

Lastly, I'm using Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition and Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Comment: show the full code please.

Comment: I use this to get the row that is selected  
        private void DataViewBox1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int ri = e.RowIndex;

Comment: and what event are you using to get the selectedRow value?

Comment: yet another strange problem. You should be sure that all you said is true, especially about how you know the selected row is always the first.

Comment: May want to verify you actually have different values being stored for each Text/Value item pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured all of this out.

First of all, there was a typo. SelectedRow should have been SelectedRows.

Also, my cast worked just fine.

Lastly, the issue is that I had set the menu to be invisible before grabbing my selected data. For whatever reason, when the window is invisible the selection defaults to 0, 0 rather than staying at its previous value.

Answer (score 1):

after analysing your code i have observed following mistakes from your code:

**1.**you are directly casting the object value to int :
Solution: here you need an explicit cast.

**2.**you are trying to get the selected Row items using following statement:

```
DataGrid_Contact.SelectedRow[0].Cells[0].Value;
```

actually above statement won't be compiled as there is no `SelectedRow[int]` Collection.
instead of that you should use `SelectedRows[int]` `Collection` as below:

```
DataGrid_Contact.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;
```

**3.**from your properties it is clear that you have disabled the `MultiRowSelect` so there is no point of getting data from multiple rows.

**Final Solution:**

*Replace this :*

```
int id = (int) DataGrid_Contact.SelectedRow[0].Cells[0].Value;
```

*With following:*

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(DataGrid_Contact.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim());
```

Comment: The `#2` might be his typo, if not he should have talked about another kind of exception.

Comment: casting as what the OP did has nothing wrong, if the `Value` is an object boxing some `int`, it should still work.

Comment: here he is doing unboxing from object to int for that ,object should be an already boxing object.

Comment: looks like you don't even try it yourself. Just make a `DataGridView` with one **int** column, try adding some rows with **int** values of that column and do it yourself. Your code works differently only when the Cell value is the string like `"3"` instead of the int `3`.

Comment: yes it is working with int column i was trying with string , Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pull the index of the selected row and then use the original structure to get the proper element.

```
     objList[yourGrid.SelectedIndex]
```